# An almost unsketchabble geometry problem.

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

Today I came across a geometry problem that looks simple to solve. But then minutes after I started, I realised that I'm stuck even before starting the proof...Here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

I started sketching the quadrilateral along with reading the question. The question says that line QR interests line AB and DC and the produced DC at S! In my quadrilateral, I am unable to connect line QR to extended line DC.

Can anyone say me why? Can anyone sketch the quadrileteral and post it?

Please don't post the proof because I'm excited in proving this question myself.

Comment: Some info on $P$ is missing: judging from the thesis, $P$ should be the midpoint of $AD$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is your diagram:
[image: diagram]